# Get 2D array indices from 1D

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So, I'm trying to iterate through all of the elements in a 2D array using one loop.

Here's where I am:

```
public class Test {
    private static final String[][] key = {
        {"`", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "=", "Backspace"}, // 0 - 13
        {"Tab", "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "[", "]", "\\"},      // 0 - 13
        {"Caps", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", ";", "'", "Enter"},       // 0 - 12
        {"Shift", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", ",", ".", "/", "\u2191"},          // 0 - 11
        {" ", "<", "\u2193", ">"}                                                       // 0 - 3
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int totalLen = 57;
        String str = "";

        for (int i = 0, row = 0, col = 0; i < totalLen; ++i, ++col) {

            if (row < key.length && i % key[row].length >= key[row].length - 1) {
                ++row;
                col = 0;
                System.out.println(str);
                str = "";
            }

            if (row < key.length)
                str += col + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

I've commented the index range for each row that the above program should output, but it doesn't as the logic is faulty. Any suggestions?

Edit: The loop condition must remain the same.

Comment: What's the point of using a "magic number" (57) and the insistence on the "condition must remain the same"? Poor readability, maintainability... What happens if the number of elements is NOT 57? Expect an exception!?

Comment: I explained the reason in a comment to one of the answers. `57` is not a magic number, it's the total number of elements in the array. `i` is used as an index for another array that was irrelevant here.

Comment: @laune
Edit: "What happens if the number of elements is NOT 57? Expect an exception!?"

First, you need to chill a bit. The number of elements is calculated earlier, so there's not possibility of it not being 57. I stripped the irrelevant details from the example.

Comment: I'm just astonished at OP's insistence to uphold an unnatural loop condition, with a final (totalLen) set to a value "calculated earlier", i.e., before compile time.

Comment: Why are you assuming it's before compile time? "Earlier" as in before it's used in this method. I wrote a loop to count it and then stored it -- run-time. I didn't need to clutter the question by including that loop. I'm just astonished by your fixation on the condition.

Comment: I'm astonished at the insistence on this loop condition because I see neither its necessity nor its advantage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution, it uses a single `while` loop and the same loop condition from the question (as requested):

```
String str = "";
int row = 0, col = 0;
int i = 0, totalLen = 57;

while (i < totalLen) {
    if (col < key[row].length) {
        str += col++ + " ";
        i++;
    } else {
        System.out.println(str);
        str = "";
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println(str); // prints the last line
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to use a `for` loop:

```
String str = "";
int totalLen = 57;

for (int i = 0, row = 0, col = 0; i < totalLen; i++) {
    str += col++ + " ";
    if (col == key[row].length) {
        row++;
        col = 0;
        System.out.println(str);
        str = "";
    }
}
```

Either snippet will produce the following output on the console:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it with two variables `row` and `col`, where `col` is incremented in the loop header, and `row` incremented conditionally in the loop body:

```
for (int row =0, col = 0 ; row != key.length ; col++) {
    System.out.println(row + " " + col);
    if (col == key[row].length-1) {
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
}
```

> The loop condition cannot be different. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

You can add `i` and stop when you reach `totalLen`, too:

```
for (int row =0, col = 0, i = 0 ; i != totalLen ; col++, i++) {
    System.out.println(row + " " + col);
    if (col == key[row].length-1) {
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
}
```

However, this is more fragile, because you get a dependency on `totalLen` being computed correctly.

Comment: Both solutions print incorrect outputs, OP's code intends to produce the `col` values for each row, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried to keep your loop condition as it is... but I don't make use of every parameter. Anyway, it should work:

```
for (int i = 0, row = 0, col = 0; i < totalLen; ++i, ++col) {
    System.out.println("row " + row + ", col " + col);
    // what ever you want to do with your loop, do it here
    // before altering the row and col parameters

    if (col == key[row].length-1) {
        col = -1;   // if end of the row, set col to -1, it will be incremented in the next loop
        row++;
        if(row==key.length){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

basically it is almost same as @dasblinkenlight did it – only I introduced a `break` condition when the `row` variable reaches the length of the `key` array. You can also test `if(i==totalLen)` but personally I find it more reliable to check the array length.

Comment: @user2570380, you where right, I corrected it. sorry